# How do I divide using *args in python?

Tags: python

I've tried the following code and got 0. I don't understand why and how to decide what sum equals to.

[image]

Comment: Why waste the time screenshotting the code when copy paste is an option?

Comment: Please always put in your `code` first - so people can easily access it and help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
def division (*args):
    sum = args[0]
    for i in args[1:]:
        sum /= i
    return sum
```

You should use comma between args when you use args like this "division(400,100,2)". On the other hand you already divide when you call the function if you call it like this "division(400/100/2)" so you are actually calling division function with 2 and in your code you assigned 1 to sum and you divide sum by your first argument and assigned quotinent to sum. I assigned first argument to sum and start args from index 1 because we assigned already index 0 to sum.

Comment: `sum` is an odd name for an accumulated division

Answer (score 0):

You're function is iterating over args fine.

The problem is that you're calculating `int(1/(400/100/2))`, which is less than zero, so casting to an integer will truncate the decimal

Maybe you should pass in a list of arguments rather than a single value. Or don't cast to an int just to print the result